# Can two PS4s log in to the same PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

Both myself and my boyfriend have PS4s.

Can I just get a single PSN account and sign both consoles into the same account, or do I need to get two separate accounts?

Answer (score 4):

So based on how you plan to do this, the answer is **No** and **Yes**.

From **[About Activation](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/about-device-activation/)**:

> **How many devices can I activate on one SEN account?**
>
> The number of devices that can be activated on your account is limited for each type of content. For example, if you have two PlayStation 3 systems activated for games content, you cannot sign-in on a third system with your PlayStation Network account information and download and play a game. You would need to deactivate one of the first two PlayStation 3 systems to allow you to activate the third.

In the table provided, only one (1) account can be activated as the primary owner for the PS4.
[image: Table of Devices and activation limits]

*So you'll need two separate accounts, as each one will be assigned a PS4 to it.*

---

Now in regards with just having one account to share, that's possible too.  From the same page:

> **On how many SEN accounts can one device be activated?**
>
> You can activate a PlayStation system on as many SEN accounts as the highest number of possible local user accounts on the system.
>
> This means that you can activate a PlayStation 4 or PlayStation 3 on up to 16 SEN accounts at once and you can activate a PS Vita, PSP or PS TV on one account at any one time.

There's a link on the page as well to explain how to [share your account's content with your "friend's" console](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/store---transactions/store-content/how-to-access-playstation-store-content-from-a-friends-playstati0/):

> 1. Create a new Local User account on the PlayStation 4 and go to  [Settings] >  [PlayStation Network] > [Sign in]. Note that system parental control settings may restrict this option.
> 2. Sign-in to your SEN account.
> 3. Select ‘No’ when you are asked if you want to activate this PlayStation system as your ‘Primary PS4’. This is to ensure you are able to continue to access your PlayStation Network content on your own PlayStation 4.
>
> *You and your friend now have temporary access to your PlayStation Network content from your friend’s system.*

Using these steps, you can make the first account, tie it to the first PS4 and buy the majority of games onto it. Make the second account, tie it to the second PS4, log-in and save the first account's credentials to the second PS4 as well to **share those games between the two systems**.

Comment: The only thing that I can't answer: What happens if you try to open the same game on both consoles. Speculating based on what we see on the PC market, it might be possible that whoever runs a game that's currently being used will kick the other player off.  I cannot verify this though.

Comment: You cannot have the same account logged into two PS4s. Each login will boot the currently logged in PS4.

Comment: You can play the same game on two consoles without issue.  My son and I play Overwatch together all the time.  He signs in to his account on my primary console.  I sign in to a second PS4.  I am a PS+ subscriber and the one who purchased Overwatch.   We have no issues both launching the game and both playing online.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to use the same account in two different PS4 is to have the internet off on one of the consoles. No online features on the offline one, but you have your savegames and can play.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to use live chat to remove systems you no longer have that you forgot to deactivate.

I did this had a phone a 3 other devices a friend of mine and one I sold.

Few days laters all devices are gone now I can register just the devices I have.